# Using CSS to position an anchor tag within a div

Tags: html, css, wordpress

In Wordpress, I am trying to alter some of the standard layout for a given theme using only CSS. The following markup produces a div with all the child elements flowing from the top (as expected).

The issue is that I have 3 of these `divs` side by side and would like the button (the `anchor` formatted as a button) to always be at the bottom of each respective `div` 
regardless of how many lines of text precede the anchor/button ("Our team... more text" in the example below but much more text for the other 2 divs). The `div` has a fixed height of 300px. I was hoping to be able to do this with CSS only. I have seen some solutions that wrap the anchor in spans or divs but I really discourage myself from editing theme code. Is there any way to get the anchor positioned at the bottom of the div regardless of the amount of text present?

Edit: This `div` is only a small part of the content on this given page. It is not the only markup present.

```
<div class="widget-front">
    <h2>The Team</h2>
    <p class="fp-text-one">Our team ...more text</p>
    <a class="btn btn-primary fp-button" href="http://www.mysite.com/the-team/" title="The Team">Read more ...</a>
</div>
```

I have a selector:

```
.widget-front > a {
    XXX
}
```

which does identify the buttons correctly but I cannot seem to get the anchor/button to be at the bottom of the div ..

For XXX I have tried (and failed)

1. `position: absolute;`
   `bottom:0`
2. `position: relative`
3. `position: relative`
   `bottom:0`
4. `vertical-align: bottom`

Comment: You have to give your anchor `a` the rule `display: block;`. Anchors are inline elements per default.

Comment: @VolkerE. When I do that and I combine "position: absolute; bottom:0", the buttons are moved around but as I resize the page, the buttons float out of this div. I likely should be clearer that this Div sits inside a lot of the WordPress code.

Comment: Post a complete code example please, including the HTML and CSS for all the involved divs.

Comment: @JoelThemmen If you give an element `position:absolute`, you take it out of so-called document flow.
It will orientate it starting x and y position from the webbrowser canvas (the document area) or from the nearest parent element having `position: relative` or `absolute` assigned to.

Comment: @VolkerE. Well that was awesome - fixed everything. Way simple. How do I mark your answer as correct?

Comment: @JoelThemmen See my answer, I'll add a link to W3C website a bit later too to it. Accept & upvote if you appreciated my help. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to give your anchor `a` the rule `display: block;`. Anchors are `inline` elements per default.

If you give an element `position: absolute`, you take it out of so-called normal document flow. It will orientate it starting x and y position from the webbrowser canvas (the document area) or from the nearest parent element having `position: relative` or `absolute` assigned to.

See http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#box-gen for more-into-detail explanation.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to upvote but I will mark it as the solution. Thanks again.